# How do I install Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have ruby 1.8.6 installed on my machine when i tried gem -v i got gem version 0.9.2
now i do install rails i tried gem install rails

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    getaddrinfo: no address associated with hostname.(SocketError)
```

why is it so and after installtion where rails is stored. and one thing net connection is required to install rails??

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/154366

http://rubyonrails.org/download

Comment: sachin i would like to know if i don't have net connection, then i do
 install rails on ruby

Comment: Amit these link will help you
http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-June/047469.html

Comment: one more where i shoud put my gem files

Answer (score 0):

Use;

http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack